# PrimeFaces update gallery when SelectOneMenu changes

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.5. I have the following code:

```
<p:panel id="containerSelectionPanel" header="Container Selection">
    <h:form id="containerSelectionForm">
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{manageContainersBean.selectedContainer}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{manageContainersBean.containerList}" var="container" itemLabel="#{container.name}" />
            <p:ajax update=":componentSelectionPanel" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>

<p:panel id="componentSelectionPanel" header="Component Selection">
    <h:form id="componentSelectionForm">
        <p:galleria id="componentGallery" var="component"
            value="#{manageContainersBean.selectedContainer.components}">
            <p:graphicImage value="#{component.preview}" title="#{component.name}" alt="#{component.name}"></p:graphicImage>
        </p:galleria>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

On startup of the website the gallery gets shown correctly. However, if I change the selection 
in the `SelectOneMenu` the gallery is just empty (nothing gets shown, the panel for "Component Selection" itself is empty).

The updating through the AJAX request works. The list of components is retrieved upon update , the preview as well as name are requested as desired. However, the HTML code generated for the updated gallery contains very few lines, way less than when loading the gallery initially, see here:

```
<ul class="ui-galleria-panel-wrapper">
    <li class="ui-galleria-panel ui-helper-hidden">
        <img id="j_idt28" alt="Have lunch" title="Have lunch">
    </li>
    <li class="ui-galleria-panel ui-helper-hidden">
        <img id="j_idt28" alt="Have brunch" title="Have brunch">
    </li>
</ul>
```

As can be seen, the newly selected container is fetched, though and the images are somewhat updated (but the inital gallery contains way more code).

I already tried updating the complete form instead of only the gallery: same result. I tried moving the gallery out of the form itself: same result. I tried using a Javascript update from the Browser console as tried [here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4840), nothing happens.

Does someone have a solution to this problem?

**Update:** I checked the server response, that gets send when the gallery should be updated. It contains exactly the same code as the initial response (when the gallery works), so there must be something wrong with JSF during rendering the response. But still no clue on how to handle this.

**Edit:** general thing: the form should not be updated, but the complete panel.

Regards,
bobbel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue being reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5237).

The temporary solution then is to modify the ajax request in the `containerSelectionForm` as follows:

```
<p:ajax 
    update=":componentSelectionPanel"           
    oncomplete="PrimeFaces.cw('Galleria','widget_componentSelectionForm_componentGallery',{id:'componentSelectionForm:componentGallery'}" />
```

In the call of `PrimeFaces.cw()` be sure to include galleria parameters like `panelWidth` in the object, that already contains the `id`.

Comment: @IrfanNasim: might be, PF is a crazy, unstable world. Unfortunately I'm not working with Java anymore for a long time already so I can't help you here. If you think the acceptance should be removed or you know how to solve it instead, just tell me. But also, it might be that just in your specific environment it doesn't work or just in my specific environment it did work. Hard to tell.