# PrimeFaces update gallery when SelectOneMenu changes, asking again

Tags: primefaces

Repeated question, i am facing again this problem.
'

[PrimeFaces update gallery when SelectOneMenu changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486788/primefaces-update-gallery-when-selectonemenu-changes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces update gallery when SelectOneMenu changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486788/primefaces-update-gallery-when-selectonemenu-changes)

Comment: yes it is duplicate, i have mentioned above in first line

Comment: My comment was auto-generated by StackOverflow. If you want to raise attention to this question, edit it and post code samples/etc. instead of linking and existing question, as the StackOverflow-Servers will else automatically delete it after a while to prevent duplicates.